# Delphi and NoSQL

Tags: database, delphi, nosql

Have anyone ever used Delphi with NoSQL databases like Mongo, CouchDB or others? Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Mongo, theres [TMongoWire](https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire) and [pebongo](http://code.google.com/p/pebongo/) (early stages). For couchDB, I believe one would interact mainly through HTTP/JSON
For Cassandra, I believe the best bet would be to somehow incorporate a supported language inside your Delphi app and use that to interact with Cassandra, or else implement a web service in a supported language and make it accessible to your Delphi application.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new full featured driver for MongoDB "mongo-delphi-driver" which can be found (with examples) here:  https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/mongo-delphi-driver.

Comment: Interesting. This set of units uses the official C MongoDB driver, so sounds one of the safest options. But you will need to link the driver to your end-user application.

Answer (score -2):

Delphi has few native NoSQL database solutions right-out-of-the-box:

- BDE & Paradox & dBase through the TDatabase & TTable API;
- TClientDataSet.

Not that I suggest them, but you have not listed your requirements.

Comment: I am quite sure that neither the BDE nor TClientDataSet fit the definition of nosql databases. In addition, the BDE supports SQL but I guess you already knew that because you restricted it to the TTable api.

Comment: Ok. What is your definition of NoSQL ?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend, there is a list of NoSQL databases